Ubuntu Pro the first five years?
If I understand correct, Ubuntu LTS (22.04, 24.04, 26.04,...) have 5 years of updates.
So Ubuntu 24.04, released in april this year have updates until april 2029.
With Ubuntu Pro I will get updates for additional five years.
But will Ubuntu Pro give me any advantage during the first five years?
Will I lose anything if I install 24.04 today and then wait until april 2029 to activate Ubuntu Pro?

Basically, yes, if you use any universe packages that got security patches via Ubuntu Pro

Ubuntu distributes updates through Pro even for supported releases that it does not distribute otherwise.
Here is a case in point. This is output from a fully supported 20.04 system showing that it got an imagemagick update through pro that isn't included in focal-updates or focal-security.
apt policy imagemagick
imagemagick:
  Installed: 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.9+esm2
  Candidate: 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.9+esm2
  Version table:
 *** 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.9+esm2 510
        510 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu focal-apps-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages


Can you please comment about the benefits of this? What is the difference, for example, between version 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.9+esm2 and 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.9? I only see an extra +esm2 in the version string!

@FedKad I don't have the slightest idea. I just noticed that occasionally they push out updates through the esm channels that aren't in the normal channels. I signed up for pro because, ironically, I am moving away from Ubuntu and need to transition this server to Debian, but it's going to be a lengthy process and I might not be done by its EOL.
